# Strange ploting on chart

Tags: bar-chart, pine-script, candlestick-chart

I have added code to detect pip size of a candle as follow:

```
BodyRange() =>
    math.abs(close - open)
CandleSize = (BodyRange() / syminfo.mintick)/10
plot(CandleSize)
```

But once I plot it and saved a code, blue vertical lines appeared on the chart. Please see attached.
Does anyone have an idea what happened?

[image]

But if I do this, all is good

```
//BodyRange() =>
    //math.abs(close - open)
//CandleSize = (BodyRange() / syminfo.mintick)/10
//plot(CandleSize)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is your plot.

Use the auto scaling and you will see.

[image]

Price of GBPUSD is around 1.24. The expression you are plotting goes from 0.1 to 31 in some cases. Therefore, it messes up your chart.

Comment: Solved with color = color.new(color.blue,100) :-) Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to see it, why do you plot it in the first place? If it is for debugging purposes, you can use `plotchar()`.

Comment: I just wanted to see number, value, but not visual presentation

Comment: Then `plotchar()` is your friend :)